Count related records i (in related table) of a 1:* relationship
I'm trying to write an Measure which will count the related number of records between a 1 to Many relationship data model. What I need to do is pull a list of Users who have more than 5 related records.
I have two tables. tbl_platformJobs and tbl_platformUsers.
I made a first column on tbl_platformJobs where I count the respective number of Jobs for each User.
Job Count = 
COUNTAX(
    FILTER(
        tbl_platformJobs, 
        tbl_platformJobs[PlatformUserId__c] = EARLIER ( tbl_platformJobs[PlatformUserId__c] )
    ),
    tbl_platformJobs[Id]
)

This is working. It see values ranging from 1 to +1200.
Then I made a column on the tbl_platformUsers table.
UserHasFiveJobs = 
IF (
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(tbl_platformJobs[Job Count]),
        RELATEDTABLE(tbl_platformJobs)          
    ) >= 5,
        "True", "False"
)

This code does not seem to do what intended. It returns all users as FALSE. Yet there should be a lot that are TRUE.
I'm wondering if I'm using the function RELATEDTABLE wrongly and/or if this column should live on the other table?
I tried a few variation of the second DAX code and all returned FALSE.

So I figure it out. The relationship between both tables were not established correctly. The matching column on the jobs table was incorrect.
